# How to change boolean result to a compatible currency value in a formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, currency, boolean

I got this formula and I got stuck trying to make it work. How do I get the result to be compatible with a currency field? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Currency).

Here is the formula:

```
IF(
    VL__Transaction_Type__c = 'Dividend',
    VL__Transaction_Type__c =  TEXT(Dividend__r.Amount__c) ,
    IF(
        VL__Transaction_Type__c = 'Debt',
        VL__Transaction_Type__c =  TEXT(Debt__r.Principal__c ) ,
        IF(
            VL__Transaction_Type__c = 'Valuation',
            VL__Transaction_Type__c = TEXT(Valuation__r.Fair_Market_Value__c),
            IF(
                VL__Transaction_Type__c = 'Share Activity',
                VL__Transaction_Type__c = TEXT(Share_Activity__r.Capital_Committed__c),
                IF(
                    VL__Transaction_Type__c = 'Repayment',
                    VL__Transaction_Type__c = TEXT(Repayment__r.Repaid_Principal__c + Repayment__r.Repaid_Interest__c), 
                    ISBLANK(null) 
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the formula and error as text rather than as an image. Images are poor for accessibility, and making suggestions about how to change your formula would require someone to manually type out the entire formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note here:

- When you are making multiple comparisons against a single field, you should consider using `CASE()` to save yourself a potentially significant amount of typing
- A formula field, in and of itself, cannot set the value of another field (you'd need a Field Update action as part of a workflow rule, process builder, or flow to do that)
- You need to ensure that all possible results from your formula match the type of your formula field

The second point means that all of the THEN parts of the IF-THEN-ELSE (which currently look like `VL__Transaction_Type__c = TEXT(Valuation__r.Fair_Market_Value__c)`) should be removed. You can't set a value here, and it doesn't make much sense to update `VL__Transaction_Type__c` in this context anyway. You're looking to simply fetch a value from a field (which depends on the value of `VL__Transaction_Type__c`).

The third point means that instead of `TEXT(Valuation__r.Fair_Market_Value__c)`, which turns numbers and such into strings, they should be replaced with simply `Valuation__r.Fair_Market_Value__c`. I'm assuming that each of the fields you're using here are Currency fields (or at the very least, numbers).

Putting that all together would give you something like this

```java
/* CASE() can take as many arguments as you can throw at it */
/* The first is always the variable value you want to match with */
/* Each pair of arguments after that is the target value to match */
/*   followed by the value to return */
/* The final argument is the default value to return if no matches */
/*   are found, and it is required */
CASE(VL__Transaction_Type__c,
    'Dividend', Dividend__r.Amount__c,
    'Debt', Debt__r.Principal__c, 
    /* Replace the remaining 0s with your desired fields */
    /* except for the final 0, which is the default value */
    'Valuation', 0,
    'Share Activity', 0,
    'Repayment', 0,
    0
)
```

Comment: Thanks Derek! I initially went with case but I did not include the zero as default at the end. Still new to this and became unsure. Appreciate the time you put in to help me out. =)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `IsBlank(null)` instead, just make it `null`. By saying IsBlank, you are returning true (as null is always blank) and hence the complain from the compiler.

Comment: I tried making it null, but I still get the same error.

Comment: You should make formula treat blank as zeros. That is the setting in formula field. You could also return 0 instead of null.

Comment: Hey Metasync, I tried your suggestion and with treating blank as zero's, it still gave me the error. I appreciate you taking the time to respond tho =)